# Button does not react to first tap in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-windowmanager

On the first start of my app I start an Intro-Activity in fullscreen with hidden navigation bar (black bar at the bottom) with:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

The `Activity` contains a `Button` to close it.

My problem is: with hidden navigation bar, the first tap on the close-button does not trigger the button, but reveals the navigation bar, only the second tap triggers the button.

Is there a way how I can close the Activity on first button tap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is described here-  https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html.   There's a new flag SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE that allows this.  Unfortunately its KitKat and above only-  older phones do not have the capability.